# How to list and copy s3 keys with non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, character-encoding

I have code which lists keys using `ListObjectsPages`->`Contents`->`Key` and copies those keys using `CopyObject`. This works in general but for some keys it's complaining `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.` The set of keys it's complaining about include keys with `+`.

- [`ListObjectsPages`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsPages) returns key "foo+bar".
- [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CopyObject) on "foo+bar" gives the `NoSuchKey` error.
- [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CopyObject) on "foo bar" (unescaped) gives the `NoSuchKey` error.

Oddly, if I use the CLI: `aws s3 cp` on "foo+bar", the copy works. But I can't use the CLI. I need to use the sdk.

I'm using [v1.8.11](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/releases/tag/v1.8.11)

As Rayfen mentioned, the plus characters could be the result of space replacement.

Update:
Everything was hashed out here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1438. Rayfen was right about needing to `QueryEscape`. I'm going to award the only current answer with the bounty since it adds useful information, but not select it as correct.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't S3 keys supposed to be URL encoded? Perhaps try https://godoc.org/net/url#QueryEscape

This is a non-go document, but here is a resource. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=215813

And yes, I googled that and it was the first result....

Comment: Good to know. I don't have control over the original key names. How can I use QueryEscape to help me?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun, you might need to `QueryUnescape` the strings to get the keys, as they are already escaped. Had it backwards. My bad.

Comment: `QueryUnescape` gives me the key with space in place of `+`, but I still get the error `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.`

Comment: Strange... one of them should work.

Comment: Interesting: you can post an asnwer and accept it (with more details than just the list to the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This details what was happening: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1438

1. The main issue was that `CopySource` needs to be url-encoded and *not* the `Key` field, which was surprising to me. (I was url-encoding both.)
2. The other issue was that I was using `path.Join` which strips out trailing `\`. This is a problem because s3 keys can have trailing `\` - which represents a sort of folder.

Answer (score 1):

The [object key and metadata document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) is clear:

> The following character sets are generally safe for use in key names:
>
> - Alphanumeric characters `[0-9a-zA-Z]`
> - Special characters `!`, `-`, `_`, `.`, `*`, `'`, `(`, and `)`

Not only + would be converted into space with, but, from the section "Characters That Might Require Special Handling" of the same page, '`:`' should also be converted back from space, which [`QueryUnescape`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape) does not do (it only convert space back to `+`).

Check if your keys include other special characters to be handled with care, like `:` (also replaced by space), `@` or `=` (replaced by `;`), or `,` and `?`.

Check in particular if the key obtained from `QueryUnescape` has a + instead of a '`:`' in the original key: that could be a space incorrectly "unescaped".

Comment: I will try `:` and let you know.